# I can´t get the type name from antd components

Tags: reactjs, antd

I whant to get the type.name from components at production build. I created https://codesandbox.io/s/w505nnql7 from sandbox here and development build works perfect. But in my production environment https://www.ginte.com.br/ you can see at the console that return 'e' where in the sandbox return 'Button'

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour. For the production build, your build tool (most likely webpack) shortens all variable names to optimise the bundle. If you have a look at your compressed javascript file you'll find out none of your variables, including variables like component names are the way they were when you wrote your code. They are now replaced with single characters so as to save memory when executing the bundle thus increasing performance.

If you want to save component name in production build, try saving the component name in a permanent way like setting it to state or as static properties. At build time these can't be affected.